# Serving MPD not from the Streaming Engine itself

Tags: video-streaming, wowza, mpeg, mpeg-dash, dash.js

I've got an http server, streaming engine server (Wowza instance) and a web client with Dash.js player.

In order to play a video, the player should recieve a URL for a mpd file.

In my current architecture, the mpd file is served through a GET request to the http server.

The server on its turn, handles the request by another GET request to the streaming engine server in order to recieve a mpd file, which is returned to the client.

Problem is, the player isn't able to play this mpd, as it ALSO expects the dash chunks to be present on the HTTP SERVER itself, instead accessing directly to the streaming engine.

Is there any way to still serve the mpd from the HTTP server but then telling the player to talk directly to the streaming engine (for the chunks) instead of the server?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  We are having issues utilizing dash over our CDN origing from Wowza due to the MPD manifest hard coding the location of the next mpd file (why isnt' this relative sheesh).

Comment: Decided to use reverse proxy technology such as Nginx, so requests would come back to the API url, but the Nginx will route the traffic to wowza instead of the app.

Comment: Gotcha, I might have mis-interpreted your issue then.  Our issue was that we are using nginx in front of it, but the index.mpd has a absolute pathed <location> tag in it, which was messing up our origining due to their session stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are scaling your Wowza server with a caching web server (such as Apache, Nginx, etc). This is possible with Wowza by using the HTTP Origin mode application types. This type of application allows you to use the HTTP caching proxy server to re-stream the MPD content from your Wowza server. The HTTP stream playback will be session-less (so any custom query parameters using client session IDs cannot be used). You will also need to configure your HTTP proxy to cache video.

To use the HTTP origin mode applications, from your Manager UI, go to Applications, and click on Add Applications. You can add either a Live HTTP Origin or VOD HTTP Origin application type.

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the base URL in the manifest file to be whatever you want it to be - in your case and using your names of the servers above, you want it to be the URL of the 'streaming server' rather than that of 'HTTP' server.

If there is no base url specified then the urls will be relative to the manifest url which is not what you want, I think.

Comment: You're right, but I'm using Wowza Streaming Engine, and I read it does not support the baseURL tag. Is there any other way?

Comment: It is your HTTP server that would need to have the base URL set - the streaming server links can be relative to the streaming server URL itself.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean.. the idea was to serve the MPD to the client once through the API, and the rest of the communication would be the client with the streaming engine (NOT via the http sevrer)

Comment: I think you mean that the client will request the appropriate media streams directly from the streaming engine rather than the HTTP server? If so then you can set the base URL in the manifest to be the URL of the streaming server and the media URLs in the manifest will be resolved relative to this base URL.

Comment: That's what I thought, look at my first comment... Wowza Streaming Engine does not support the base URL tag in the manifest...https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?508-How-to-do-MPEG-DASH-streaming

Comment: The answer has no relation to Wowza